# Installing Python package from source using Microsoft Visual Build Tools 2017

Tags: python, windows, build-tools, kenlm

I have a python package that is failing to install due a dependency on Windows build tools.

Things I have tried:

1. Install latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (AFAIK it should contain Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0).
2. Install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 directly from here https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017.
3. Put `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools` on my path explicitly.
4. Uninstall all of Visual Studio and try again.

So far no luck.  I tried restarting the terminal, restarting the computer etc...  I am using GitBash, which might be relevant, although it never causes me any problems otherwise.

When I installed the tools, I made sure to check the 'Visual C++ Build Tools' workflow which selected some subset of the many line items that were available under the Individual Components tab.

In my example below I'm installing a language model but I believe that my issue is more general than that.  I'm finding it difficult to understand which of the many components are relevant to my task.  What I would like to know is: how do I validate that I have the build tools configured correctly and that I have the correct version?  Any advice or guidance here would be much appreciated.

error:

```
$ pip36 install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
Collecting https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
  Downloading https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip (526kB)
Installing collected packages: kenlm
  Running setup.py install for kenlm: started
    Running setup.py install for kenlm: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\users\ks99999999\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe  -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ks99999999\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-tfn5ym94-b uild\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close ();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ks99999999\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r2e ogfmd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'kenlm' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http: //landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\ks99999999\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptool s, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ks99999999\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-tfn5ym94-build\\setup.py';f=getatt r(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __ file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ks99999999\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r2eogfmd-record\install-rec ord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ks99999999\Ap pData\Local\Temp\pip-tfn5ym94-build\
```

Comment: Have you been adding it to your Windows PATH or your bash path?

Comment: What version of `setuptools` are you using?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting after the installation? Also, are you sure the error is the same after you installed the build tools?

Comment: Also, Visual C++ 14 is in VS 15, not VS 17. I've had instances where it doesn't work with VS 17 due to explicitly requiring 14.0; [This link worked for me](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)

Comment: @Priansh I added it to my PATH environment variable under advanced settings.

Comment: @sytech I rebooted several times and it is the same error after I installed the build tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio doesn't ship out-of-box with any VC compiler (or any compiler generally).  Your installation is modularized, so you will have to make sure that you did, in fact, install a visual c++ with your installation of VS2017.  Moreover, IIRC, VS2017 ships with Microsoft Visual C++ 15.0.  [You can install the 14.0 compiler with the Standalone Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 build tools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_with_Visual_Studio_2017_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29).  Make sure you have the correct setuptools version as well.

You can check which version of MSVC is installed by looking at Start Menu -> Add / Remove Programs and checking in the list of installed programs.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, so no start menu.  I checked in settings and I can see that the 2017 version of Visual Studio, still not sure how to check Visual C++ version directly...

Comment: It looks like I didn't select the correct subset of options when setting up the build tools initially.  I did that and now I am past this step.